# Will the rise of technology in the 21st century lead to an electrical apocalypse?

Tags: attacks, virus

I saw a comic in the newspaper the other day showing a person locked in his house that had been overrun by hackers. It seemed a bit far-fetched but it got me thinking, In this new-age, with everything being connected to the internet, isn't there a huge potential for disaster. For instance with laptops, a group of hackers managed to remotely speed up a laptop's fan so much that the computer exploded like a bomb, or with driver-less being connected to the internet, a hacker could disable the brakes, change the car's destination or speed it up, could they not? My question is, would the introduction of internet connectivity to practically everything lead to mass hackings and virtual destruction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the main fear yes. You can already see it in the presidential race for example, it's unlike anything we've seen. The public feels there is not enough transparency and a few vigilante hacker go out to get that transparency.

A few days ago millions of internet-connected camera's started to blast the main infrastructure of the internet, knocking offline a few of the top sites for a large part of america. So that's already a moderate version of what you're describing. A larger version could knock out critical systems.

[And forget about driverless cars, current cars can also be taken over because of ABS and other systems.](https://youtu.be/OobLb1McxnI)

Answer (score 0):

A huge potential for disaster I wouldn't say (talking about banks and credit cards etc...), because you have security professionals trying to trace the "bad hackers" everyday, and eventually they are caught. So what's the point of making those kind of things when you will be caught? People that have that kind of knowledge usually don't make those mistakes. 
I believe every system is "hackable" tho, and we wouldn't connect a nuclear bomb (for example) to a online server, THAT would be at risk of a huge disaster for sure.
Yes you can speed up a laptop's fan, but it would never explode, try to make a bomb out of a fan.
You could remove the brakes of a car if the car AND the brakes were online, yes, but why would you make that a possible thing to do? It won't happen you are safe ;)

Answer (score 0):

In some sense, it's already happening.

The DDoS attack on Krebs:
https://krebsonsecurity.com/2016/09/krebsonsecurity-hit-with-record-ddos/

The Nissan LEAF car hack:
https://www.troyhunt.com/controlling-vehicle-features-of-nissan/

The number of data breaches seems to increase by every year?